# Get inserted Id from NativeQuery Hibernate 5.2+

Tags: hibernate, postgresql-9.5, hibernate-5.x, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

I am using the following code to run native sql queries on hibernate (SQLQuery) has been deprecated.

```
private static int executeUpdate(String sql) {
    int result = 0;
    Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
    NativeQuery nativeQuery = session.createNativeQuery(sql);
    int executeUpdate = nativeQuery.executeUpdate();
    tr.commit();
    return executeUpdate;
}
```

It all works fine but I want the same method to also return the id of the last inserted element, I want the way to be table agnostic.

[[EDIT]]

One way to do this can be to pass a native query with `returning id`
and then use this code:

```
private static int executeUpdate(String sql) {
        int result = 0;
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> ret = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
        NativeQuery nativeQuery = session.createNativeQuery(sql);
        ret = nativeQuery.list();
        tr.commit();
        return Integer.parseInt(ret.get(0).get("id").toString());
    }
```

Can there be some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that whit `getSingleResult()` , in your example

```
private static int executeUpdate(String sql) {
    int result = 0;
    Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
    NativeQuery nativeQuery = session.createNativeQuery(sql);

    //here I'm assuming you are getting a BigInteger as result, change accordingly
    BigInteger executeUpdate = (BigInteger) nativeQuery.getSingleResult(); 
    tr.commit();
    return executeUpdate;
}
```

Even if the javadoc says that `getSingleResult()` is used for `SELECT`, looks working anyway for me.

Hope this helps

Comment: Nope fails and throws, `14:52:25.359 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - No results were returned by the query.`

Comment: The difference in the method's result might have something to do with the underlying SQL engine. I use PostgreSQL, and it fails in that case. Added that tag to the question.

Comment: Might be, I've tried with different db without any error :(

Comment: Undocumented features tend to behave like that :)